# React Native: If I'm updating targetSdkVersion, should I update anything else?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, target-sdk, targetsdkversion

I'm upgrading the version of React Native OneSignal to 4.8.0, and in the [ChangeLog](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases/tag/4.8.0) it says `change your Android targetSdk to 33`. I currently have `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` both set to 31.

**What I Want To Know:**

1. Should I also set `compileSdkVersion` to 33?
2. If I'm updating one of both of these properties, is there anything else in my code that I should update?

Comment: I have same questions!